# Unable to reference BrushResource in linked ResourceProject from Style ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a project in my application where I keep all of my Resources & reusable custom control classes (including styles, brushes, custom controls, etc.).

The App.xaml file of my Application's "Main" project references the ResourceLibrary file that references all my organized ResourceDictionary files like so:

```
     <Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ControlResources;component/ResourceDictionaries/ResourceLibrary.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Simple Styles.xaml"/>     
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" /> 

    </ResourceDictionary>


</Application.Resources>
```

Note: I am following this article [here](http://projekt202.com/blog/2010/xaml-organization/) that includes a big-fix (the Rectangle style included above).

Below is a snapshot of what my "ControlResources" project looks like.

[image: This is what my "ControlResource" project outline looks like]

Referencing the style and customControl resources works great when I reference them from my main project, "GlenwareMaster", but when referencing the brush resources under "Brushes" from any of the style resources, the application is clearly not finding them.

My question: Can I just add a project-self-referencing link (an inherent right-click blend feature?). How can I get the style ResourceDictionaries to locate the Brush ResourceDictionaries in the same project?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you referencing the brush resource dictionaries in your style dictionaries? Make sure you're using pack URIs and that they are correct.

My standard practice is to use the absolute pack uri format in any resource dictionaries that I plan to reference within another resource dictionary- leads to less errors if you end up moving it to another project in the future. When you reference brushes in your common style resource dictionaries, Try something like:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ControlResources;component/ResourceDictionaries/Brushes/MyBrushes.xaml"/>
```

You can read more about Pack URIs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much for responding so quickly, @Jesper . Is there any way that you know of that would allow me to make the Color/Brush ResourceDictionary available to all other ResourceDictionary files of the same project without having to re-reference the source file again for each file? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Not that I am aware of. If you had a set of shared resource dictionaries that you wanted to include all over that project, you could merge them into one common dictionary and reference that if you're worried about the number of merged dictionaries. Otherwise you have to specify it one way or another.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It's clear to me now that this is my only option.